# Find the Missing Side Length Value on A Triangle

Tags: geometry

https://ibb.co/gYcKWv

[image]

> Refer to the image in the link, in which angles $ABE$ and $CDE$ are equal in size, and various segments have been marked with their lengths. Find $x$.

I thought that $\bigtriangleup CDE$ is similar to $\bigtriangleup CAB$, therefore, I made the following proportions $\frac{CB}{CA} = \frac{CE}{CD} \rightarrow \frac{12}{(x+2)} = \frac{4}{x}$ and got that $x = 1$. Am I incorrect? If yes, then what would be the proper approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flip the smaller triangle to setup your ratio. That would setup a ratio of $\frac{CB}{CA}=\frac{CD}{CE}$  If you were to imagine that the drawing is to scale, you could think$\frac{\text{C to longer side}}{\text{C to shorter side}}=\frac{\text{C to longer side}}{\text{C to shorter side}}$

$$\frac{CB}{CA} = \frac{CD}{CE} \rightarrow \frac{12}{(x+2)} = \frac{x}{4}$$

Comment: I found two values of $x$: -8, 6. However, it would only make sense for 6 to be the answer.

Comment: Correct. 6 is the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No prob. Oftentimes you will set up a quadratic equation to solve a real life problem where negative numbers don't make sense. In those cases you generally disregard any negative solution you get.